# Where is better place to store data in Angular 2? Service or localStorage?

Tags: angular, local-storage

I'm new in Angular2. Some users prefer store all data in localStorage. Others prefer save data into service object.

What is the correct way? What is the pro/contro of both method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use local storage when you want to store the data across application instances, like cookies, but better.

Use objects in services for most application data that is not shared across sessions. Most of your data should be in services.